# Use $x,y$ or $z$ for complex functions?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

> Say I have $f:\mathbb C\rightarrow \mathbb C$, so 
>   $$
> f(x+iy)=f(z)=u(x,y)+iv(x,y)
> $$

*Q1:* Does it mean the functions $u$ and $v$ are
\begin{align}
u,v:\mathbb R^2\rightarrow \mathbb R
  \tag{1}
\end{align}
Or
\begin{align}
u,v:\mathbb C\rightarrow \mathbb R
\tag{2}
\end{align}

*Q2:*
The notation $u(x,y)$ and $v(x,y)$ implies that $$u,v:\mathbb R^2\rightarrow \mathbb R$$

But if $u,v:\mathbb C\rightarrow \mathbb R$, shouldn't we instead write $u(z)$ and $v(z)$?

Answer (score 1):

The functions $u,v$ obviously have two real arguments and take a real value. Hence $\mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R$. This is why you can't write $u(z),v(z)$.

In some sense, there is an implicit function $\iota$ that decomposes a complex number in a pair of real, imaginary components,

$$\iota:\mathbb C\to\mathbb R^2:\iota(z)\to(x,y)=(\Re(z),\Im(z))$$ and

$$f(z)=u(\iota(z))+iv(\iota(z)).$$